# Autofiltering from a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA macro for post processing data, and it currently has a "Raw Data" sheet for the first sheet, and my post processing tools on the second sheet. What I have so far is a button that will search the data and create plots for the desired variables, but it pulls data for all of the test points. What I want to do is to be able to filter by test point from the data review sheet. What would be ideal would be to have an autofilter type dropdown menu on my post processing sheet where the test point can be selected, and the data on the previous sheet would be filtered.

Here's the search function I've been using:

```
Dim TestPt As Long
Dim rows As Long
rows = Sheets(1).UsedRange.rows.Count
'
Sheets(1).Select
 Cells.Find(What:="TargetTestPointNumber", After:=ActiveCell,    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
TestPt = ActiveCell.Column
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you needed exactly. But this code does a comparison between the value you want and the data sheet. If its = it will copy it to Row D so if you have stuff there you will need to change it. Also it assumes the data is in row 1.

```
            Dim i As Long, lastRowD As Long, lastRowA As Long

        With Sheets("datasheetname")
        lastRowA = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRowA
        lastRowD = .Range("D" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "testvalue" Then
            .Cells(lastRowD, 4).Value = "testvalue"
        End If
        Next i

        .Range("D1", "D" & lastRowD).Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'datasheetname'!$D$1:$D" & lastRowD)


        End With
```

note youll need to change test value and datasheetnames. As well as any of the column info. I tried it and it works. I just have no idea if this is what you need. If you need to copy more than 1 row, you would change in the if how many to do.

`.cells(lastRowD,5).value= .cells(i,2).value` etc

Comment: Tim, I don't think this is quite what I need... What I want to have is something like a Combobox on Sheets(2) that will filter the rows on Sheets(1), based on the values in the column found by the search function I posted. Regardless of how it is filtered, I need it to only show the rows on sheets(1) with the value that is selected on Sheets(2). I'll see if I can use your code to get what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the messy code, but I found this to work for me. Basically I copied the unique test point value to the other sheet, linked them to a ComboBox, and linked a macro to run with the ComboBox to autofilter the data on the other sheet. I'm sure there has to be a better way, but it works for me.

```
   Sub ValueSelectionData()
    '
    Dim TestPt As Long
    Dim rows As Long
    Dim Value As Long 'used to select test point
    rows = Sheets(1).UsedRange.rows.Count 'Row count on data sheet
    Value = Sheets(2).Cells(2, 6).Value 'value linked to ComboBox selection
    '
    Sheets(2).Columns("A:A").ClearContents
    Sheets(1).Select
    Cells.Find(What:="TargetTestPointNumber", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate 'searches for test point column in data
  TestPt = ActiveCell.Column 

  Range(Sheets(1).Cells(2, TestPt), Sheets(1).Cells(rows, TestPt)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)), Unique:=True

If Value > 0 Then

     Sheets(1).Select
     Cells.Find(What:="TargetTestPointNumber", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
TestPt = ActiveCell.Column
Value = Sheets(2).Cells(2, 6).Value 'desired test point to filter for
Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(1, TestPt), Sheets(1).Cells(rows, TestPt)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Value 'autofilters data for desired test point
Else
   'Clear all auto filters
    If Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode Then
    Sheets(1).ShowAllData

End If
End If
End Sub
```